# C# new RDOSession() throws exception

Tags: c#, outlook-redemption

I'm trying to create Outlook email using Redemtion.

Part of my code:

```
RDOSession session = new RDOSession(); // throws exception 1
session.Logon(ProfileName, Password, false, true);

Send_Redemption(mail, ref session, MoveToFolder);

session.Logoff();
```

Exception 1:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {29AB7A12-B531-450E-      8F7A-EA94C2F3C05F} 
>       failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Can someone suggest tell me why I get this, and hoe to correct that?

Answer (score 4):

The error means Redemption was not registered. Have you tried to re-register it using regsvr32.exe?

What are the bitnessess of your app, Redemption and Outlook? 

See http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/faq.htm#ErrorCreatingRedemptionObject for more details.

You might also want to use [RedemptionLoader](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/security.htm#redemptionloader) - this way you won't have to deal with the registry at all.

Answer (score 0):

I found this old post with the same problem and nothing here helped. I tried running the installer do the manual registration. No help. Checked for 32bit/64bit conflict but no.

What finally helped for me was to search registry for all entries with redemption.dll. There was maybe 10 of them with a few different CLSID. I deleted them all and ran the installer again and it started working.